# What advantages does a GUI offer for VCS users?

Tags: git, user-interface, version-control

I'm giving a talk in a couple of weeks, to a bunch of scientists, introducing them to VCSs (or trying to inspire them to use VCSs for those who already know). One thing I'm wary of is scaring people off with a bunch of commandline tools, when they're used to GUIs. So I was trying to think about what advantages a GUI offers to a VCS user, over commandline tools, but I really can't think of many.

Are there any advantages, other than the obvious "stay inside your comfort zone" ones, like using a mouse and not having to memorise commands?

General answers are good, but answers specific to particular VCSs or GUIs are welcome too (I'll be giving the talk using git as a main example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm addicted to the command line, but I find the GUI representations of commit histories much more intuitive to read than `git log --graph`. GUIs allow users to analyze and manipulate the repository directly from the history view, which is handier than copy/pasting hashes, or counting back from HEAD, or finding the right plumbing command, etc. GUIs also give users a nicer interface for config settings. (I've lost track of how many times I've messed up a setting because I didn't escape a quotation mark or something.)

You mention not having to memorize commands and staying inside a comfort zone, but I think those are a fairly significant points for a tool as complex as Git. There are zillions of Git commands, with zillions of options, some but not all of which apply to multiple commands (`--dry-run`, anyone?), and some but not all of which use different formats (`-n 1` vs. `-1`?). For most users, clicking a button like they do for every other program they use is far more intuitive and convenient than skimming through `git help` when you can't remember if you should be using `master..origin/master` or `master origin/master` or `origin master`. (As a geek, skimming through `git help` is part of my fun, but that's not true for any of my teammates at work who use GUIs. They recognize that Git streamlines their workflow, but they don't want to devote much thought to the tool itself. They just want to get stuff done.)

Comment: Great answer, I'd also add the if you do most of your work inside an IDE then most VCS have plugins, so you don't have to change windows or go in to a seperate tool to do the VCS "stuff"

Answer (score 1):

Well, 'I' Think that :

1) the command line does not offer any 'preventive control', 
2) the command line can not guide the user, by proposing only the limited set of commands that can be executed in a particular situation. Well, not as well as a GUI would do.

Two -extreme- analogies to explain that :

Could you imagine flying a plane through a bunch of command lines ? It technically should be possible, but without a cockpit and its monitoring tools giving you in real time - and without requiring you to ask for - any relevant information you need to pilot, it is very easy to imagine that it would be much harder. Guis like plane cockpits offer you preventive control on what you are doing. They can even give you information that you didn't imagine the existence, because you never heard about the equivalent command line before.

Do you feel more confortable on finding your way while driving in a city or in a desert ? In the first case road signs give you some indication about where you are going, and since roads are roads, you anyway have a limited choice of ways. The same way, GUI act as a facade over a set of atomic command lines, regrouping them in singles and coherents high level operations, described as road signs in menus. In the second case, you can virtually go anywhere - possibly in a wrong direction -, and you have to trace your way by yourself, scheduling your own checkpoints. This is the same with command line.

I think these ideas are relevant for VCSs too.